# How do i make something to run a program/do something when a client connecting to my server and how do i make the server to return to the client?

Tags: java, c#, android

This is my webserver working code on the pc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in form1 constructor:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://+:8098/");//"http://localhost:8080/test/");
ws.Run();
```

And a method in form1:

```
public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
        }
```

And in the client side java code:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.AndroidRuntimeException;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

//import com.adilipman.webservertest.DebugServer;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

        currentActivity = this;

        initTTS();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.  Ensure any created loaders are
     * now started.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        TextToSpeechServer.main(null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int i) {

                        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
                                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                                mTts.setPitch(1);
                                mTts.speak(textforthespeacch, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String textforthespeacch = "";
    public static void TextToSpeak(String text) {
        textforthespeacch = text;
    }

    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private Path circlePath = new Path();

        public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    circlePath.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            byte[] response = Get(null);
                            if (response!=null)
                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(response.toString());


                        }
                    });
                    t.start();




                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // nothing to do
                    circlePath.reset();

                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            // Schedules a repaint.
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr="http://10.0.0.2:8098";
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);

            byte[] bufOut;

            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }


            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }



}
```

First i'm running the server on the pc.
Then i'm running the program on the android when i make a touch on my smartphone the client connect to the server on the pc.

Now what i want to do is two things:

1. When connecting to the pc server do something. Once my device is connected to the pc server do something for example show a message like:

`MessageBox.Show("connected");`

2. After connected and if connected using a flag or something return a string to the client. I have on the pc a method called SendData i used it to send a string to a server on my android device:

```
private void SendDataToServer()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.3:8080/?say=hello? im here ");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
```

The question is if i need to use this method if i want to return something from my pc server to the client side ?

Comment: `when i make a touch on my smartphone the client connect to the server on the pc`. That is only half the story. It connects and then disconnects. Http is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: `I have on the pc a method called SendData i used it to send a string to a server on my android device:`. Why would you have a -web-server on your android device too? That makes no sense. Your Android client should just make simple GET or POST http statements with some info. The server will then send the requested info as response. The Android client reads that info.

Comment: You should send the server response as the http response to the client. To get the proper response, parse the request and prepare the response on server-side.